Different results for scipy-minimize using SLSQP dependent upon initalized values
I am using scipy.minimize in an attempt to optmize the inputs to my function.
I have a given amount of budget/hours and 6 inputs where I'm trying to get the highest return from the input mix. Each of these 6 inputs has a non-linear concave-shaped return. That is each of the response curve 'saturates' in a curve similar to what you see in a logiarimic curve.
My issue is that this all seems highly sensitive to the initial_guess  values that are passed in.
I ran 1000 simulations of random numbers for the initial guess.  I got various optimized values.  I thought that I would consistently get the same result but each time it is different.  Again the response curve for all of them is similar to a logarithmic curve.
My graident_fuction is correct, my objective_function is as well.
I just don't know what is wrong or what I could be misinterpretting.
optimization = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, method='SLSQP', jac=gradient_function, bounds=boundaries, constraints=[{'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraints_function}], options={'maxiter': maxiter})


Are the objective values of these solutions different, or are the X values different, or both?

"My graident_fuction is correct" Are you sure? How large is the error measured by check_grad?

There are two cases.

The problem is a non-convex problem. Then this behavior is to be expected. SLSQP is a local solver, so it will find a local optimum depending on the initial point. It is great that you provide exact gradients (much better than let the solver do finite differences). But exact gradients do not change that SLSQP is a local solver. If you want to find global solutions (independent of the starting point), you need to use a global solver.

The problem is convex. You, somewhat vaguely, seem to indicate this is the case. A local solver should converge to a global optimum. There may be different optimal points, but all should have the same objective.


